# createRecord creates an empty instance when catching errors

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am wondering why i am getting an empty instance each time i try to save a newly created record and it fails. I see like an empty record being added in my posts object only when i display errors.
Also i tried sorting posts which let me see the top recent created posts but the behavior is kinda odd, because as soon as the post is created, it shows at the end and then immediately goes to the top. I am wondering if this is normal or maybe there is a way to wait for the server response and push the record with some sort of fade in effect, etc. Thanks.

### index.hbs

```
<form {{action "savePost" post on="submit"}}>
  <div class="form-group {{if errors.error-content "has-error has-feedback"}}">
    {{textarea value=post
      rows=3
      placeholder="What are you thinking?" 
      id="content" 
      class="form-control"}}
    <small class="help-block text-danger">
      {{errors.error-content}}
    </small>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <button type="submit" 
              class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
              Create new post
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

{{#each sortedPosts as |post|}}
  <article class="wrapper">
    <p>{{post.content}}</p>
  </article>
{{else}}
  <article class="wrapper">
    <p>NO CURRENT POSTS TO SHOW!</p>
  </article>
{{/each}}
```

### post.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  content: DS.attr('string'),
  created_at: DS.attr('date')
});
```

### index.js route

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('post');
  },

  actions: {
    savePost(content) {
      const newPost = this.store.createRecord('post', {
        content: content
      });
      newPost.save().then(() => {
        this.controller.set('post', '');
        this.controller.set('errors', []);
      }).catch((resp) => {
        let errors = {};
        resp.errors.forEach((error) => {
         errors[`error-${error.field}`] = error.messages[0];
        });
        this.controller.set('errors', errors);
      });
    },

    willTransition() {
      this.controller.get('post').rollbackAttributes();
      this.controller.set('errors', []);
    }
  }
});
```

### index.js controller

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  sortProp: ['created_at:desc'],
  sortedPosts: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProp')
});
```

Comment: Could you explain more what do you mean exactly with: "getting an empty instance each time i try to save a newly created record and it fails. I see like an empty record being added in my posts object only when i display errors." ? 

Does it mean you see the created record in the list - although it failed to save it because it had errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your `this.store.createRecord` will always create a new record. So if your `.save()` fails, you can unload the record, or you don't create your new record there, or save it for the next `.save()`.

The question is a bit why your `.save()` fails. If its some kind of validation error, and the user fixes them and saves the post again, I would recommend to use the same, earlier created post again, modify it and try to `.save()` it again.

Another approach is to filter the records you display on the [`isNew`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isNew) flag.

With that I would bind the `textarea` directly to a fresh record. A computed property like this could be nice:

```
newRecord: Ember.computed('_newRecord.isNew', {
    get() {
        if(!get(this, '_newRecord') || !get(this, '_newRecord.isNew')) {
            set(this, '_newRecord', this.store.createRecord('post'));
        }
        return get(this, '_newRecord');
    }
})
```

Then you can directly bind your `texturea`'s `value` to `newRecord.content` and just `.save()` this in your action.

For all kind of animations, checkout [liquid fire](http://ember-animation.github.io/liquid-fire/).